# App en C# falla al grabar una frase en NFC, y al leerlo aparece solo la letra 'c'

Tags: c#, nfc, acr122u-a9

Tengo una regrabadora de NFC por USB, modelo ACR122U-A9 (ACS).

Instalé sin problema los drivers del disco compacto que venía con el dispositivo. También descargué e instalé manualmente en el proyecto el NuGet para ACR122U de Sidesoft para dispositivos (ACS) ACR122U.

Usando un código ejemplo en C#, en la web de sidesoft, uso estas lineas de código que os comparto por aquí.

Trato de que: la primera vez luego de ejecutar una app y llamar al método de inicialización.

- Al colocar un NFC la primera vez, grabe "Hello World!".
- Y luego al retirar el NFC, y colocarlo de nuevo, lo lea y muestre la lectura como String.

Sin embargo, al grabar el NFC, el metodo Write() devuelve y muestra FALSE.

Y luego, al quitar y recolocar el NFC, lo lee y muestra solo la letra 'c'.

(Esperaba que mostrarse la cadena "Hello World!" recien grabada, y no 'c')

No hay diferencia entre usar un NFC de 1 Kb que viniera con el lector/grabador, o usando un Mifare de 8 Kb. He probado con estos dos tipos de NFC, y hacen lo mismo.

Aqui os dejo el código modificado que uso a partir del las lineas de ejemplo de la página de sidesoft.

Saludos bros.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Sydesoft.NfcDevice;

class acr122u_CSdrive
{
static ACR122U oneDr = new ACR122U();

static string outTEXT = "";
static string NEXTwrite = "Hello World!";

internal static void _acr122u_CSdrive (ACR122U drive_ACR)
{
   drive_ACR.Init(false, 200, 4, 4, 200);
   drive_ACR.CardInserted += Acr122u_CardInserted;
   drive_ACR.CardRemoved += Acr122_CardRemoved;
   oneDr = drive_ACR;
   MessageBox.Show("Inicializada grabadora de NFCS (ACS) ACR122U-A9");
}

private static void Acr122u_CardInserted (PCSC. ICardReader reader)
   { 
    out TEXT = "Lector Regrabador de NFC. (ACS ACR122U-A9)\n" + "Unique ID:"+ BitConverter.ToString(oneDr.GetUID (reader)).Replace("-", "");

if (NEXTwrite != "")
   {
   byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(NEXTwrite);
   bool ret = oneDr.WriteData(reader, data);
   out TEXT += "\nEscribiendo:" + NEXTwrite + " " + ret.ToString(); 
   MessageBox.Show(outTEXT);
   NEXTwrite ="";
   }
else
   {
   string dato= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oneDr.ReadData(reader));
   outTEXT += "\nLeido:" + dato;  
   MessageBox.Show(outTEXT); 
   }
}
   
private static void Acr122_CardRemoved()
  {
  MessageBox.Show("NFC Retirado");
  }
}
```

Buscando en otros hilos sobre este asunto,  he leido acerca de una librería para acceso de USB a espacios de aplicación: **libusb**.

No lei que fuese necesario instalar esta librería en la pagina de sidesoft, ni en otras reseñas sobre este dispositivo.

Sin embargo, en un hilo sobre un problema de una grabadora de NFC, comentaban que habilitaron la comunicacion instalando esta librería.

¿Sabéis si es que para comunicar y usar la grabadora de NFCs ACS como esta, es necesario instalar a parte de lo que ya disponga Windows 10 para acceder a USB, la libusb? Creo que no, pregunto igualmente porque nonestoy seguronde esto.

Hoy he probado de todo, desinstalar el nuget, volverlo a imstalar.

Mover el codigo dssde la clase en que lo puse, al .cs de Form1 del proyecto, y nada.

En las pruebas de hoy, devolvio igualmente FALSE al grabar, aunque recuperó una cadena vacia al leer el NFC grabado.

Vi que este dispositivo en mi equipo/instalación, necesitaba de un Hub-USB con alimentación propia para detectar, y por tanto grabar y leer NFC. Así que lo recoloqué de esta forma en un Hub-USB activo.

Comment: Verifica que se está instalando bien los datos, descarga en el móvil: "NFC Tools" y realiza una lectura desde ahí.

Comment: He instalado NFC Tools en mi movil, y he comprobado que el programa no está grabando en el NFC, y que cuando grabo una frase con la app, en el PC lee 'c'. Ahora me pregunto, los parametros de inicialización, ¿Pueden ser incorrectos para su funcionamiento, protocolo o configuración de uso y/o modelo de tarjeta NFC? ¿Puede ser esta la causa de que no funcione correctamente la grabadora / programa?

Comment: Sí, es correcto. ¿Qué dice la documentación del programa? Me late que el problema es que grabas cadenas de texto cuando deberías grabar ese mismo valor en hexadecimal.

Comment: El ejemplo del codigo del programa sin modificación, graba "Hello World", y lo graba Codificándolo de String a un array bytes en UTF8. Y de vuelta al leer igual, de bytes a un string de UTF8 con  Encoding.GetString().

Comment: He visto una cosa, las caracteristicas de la grabadora de NFCs que me.he comprado, dice que trabaja con el standard ISO 14443 A/B. Sin embargo he observado, que la marca da unos guide lines code generales. Buscando sobre el asunto a cerca de este standard, me encuentro con unq codificacion para los de Tipo B CRC_B. Sin embargo no tengo idea de que hacer ni resolver esto.

Comment: Te comparto una experiencia y quizás te de alguna idea: Hace tiempo me tocó trabajar con unos drivers a los que le tenías que mandar instrucciones en hexadecimal seguidos de más código hexadecimal con los valores a procesar, el resultado era otro hexadecimal. Había que prestar atención a El Bit más significativo y a El Bit menos significativo. Saludos.